# Laravel seeds и factories для связанных таблиц

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Пытаюсь освоиться с seeds, factories и использование Faker в Laravel 5.6. Пытаюсь заполнять фейковыми данными связанные таблицы.

### Связь один ко многим

app\Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

app\Category.php

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала я описываю factories

databasse\factories\CategoriesFactory.php

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = rand(2, 3), $variableNbWords = true),
        'slug' => $faker->slug(3)
    ];
});
```

database\factories\ProductsFactory.php

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'category_id' => rand(1, 10), //Использую rand между 1 и 10, т.к буду создавать 10 категорий в seeds
        'name' => $faker->text(45),
        ...
    ];
});
```

В seeds я описываю вызов каждой фабрики. И регистрирую каждый seed в `DatabaseSeeder.php`

database\seeds\CategoriesTableSeeds.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(\App\Category::class, 10)->create();
    }
}
```

database\seeds\ProductsTableSeeds.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class ProductsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(\App\Product::class, 1000)->create();
    }
}
```

database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
         $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
         $this->call(ProductsTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Т.к. в `CategoriesTableSeeds.php` создаю 10 категорий, то в `database\factories\ProductsFactory.php` для поля `category_id` я вызываю `rand(1, 10)`. Но мне этот способ кажется не оптимальным. Можно ли как-то автоматизировать и этот процесс? Оптимальным не кажется мне ещё и потому, что хоть для связи один ко многим это ещё можно применить, а вот для связи многие ко многим - едва ли.

### Связь многие ко многим

Помимо всего прочего продуктам можно назначать метки

app\Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function labels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Label');
    }
}
```

app\Label.php

```
class Label extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал фабрику для создания меток.

database\factories\LabelsFactory.php

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Label::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = rand(1, 3), $variableNbWords = true),
    ];
});
```

Что делать дальше я не знаю. Фабрику или сидера описать для связи многие ко многие не представляю как, потому что как минимум нужно будет создать модель этой таблицы `label_product`. А зачем модель, если связи и без того описаны? В общем это второй вопрос, который возник при разборе темы.

Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сгенерировать фековые данные для ваших связей в бд? 
Вот пример для "многие ко многим":

```php
// Создать 5 Foo's и Bar для кажлого
factory(App\Foo::class, 5)->create()->each(function($foo) {
    $foo->bars()->save(factory(App\Bar::class)->make());
});
```

Если надо изменять pivot, то можете попробовать:

```
// Создать 5 Foo's и Bar для кажлого
factory(App\Foo::class, 5)->create()->each(function($foo) {
    $bar = factory(App\Bar::class)->make()
    $foo->bars()->save($bar);
    $bar->pivot->price = 12; 
    $bar->pivot->save();
});
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если есть, например таблица юзеров, таблица ролей и их таблица многие ко многим роли_юзер, то мне понадобится создать модель для этой таблицы роли_юзер, потому что я не смогу создать фабрику (в фабрике нужно давать ссылку на модель?

Comment: Стандартно я создаю только две модели, где указываю связи belongsToMany. И нет нужды тогда создавать модель для третьей таблицы. Но чтобы создать фабирку, нужна модель

Comment: Вам надо просто иметь две фактории для моделей, если надо изменить pivot то можете сделать это так: `$product->pivot->price = 12;
$product->pivot->save();` Как генерировать данные при belongToMany я дал в своем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Подобная история. Благодаря предыдущему ответу узнал о методе ->each. Спасибо!) Сейчас юзаю Laravel 8. Создаю фейкером 5 **отделов** и создаю 25 **работников** которых назначаем в один из 5-ти отделов. Связи как обычно, прописаны в моделях (m2m)

--DepartmentSeeder.php--

```
public function run()
{
    \App\Models\Department::factory()->count(5)->create();
}
```

--EmployeeSeeder.php--

```
public function run()
{
    Employee::factory()->count(25)->create()
        ->each(function ($employee) {
            $department = Department::find(rand(1, 5));
            $employee->departments()->save($department);
        });
}
```

Сейчас еще подумаю как одного работника в несколько отделов назначить (в сидерах описать)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, это ответ на вопрос ТС или новый вопрос?

Comment: Это так, делюсь мыслями. А вообще все же выплыл вопрос. Как случайным образом одного работника в несколько случайных отделов одновременно назначить, с помощью этого сидера. В описанном коде выше --EmployeeSeeder.php-- имеем, что каждый сотрудник попадает только в один отдел.

Comment: А вас не смутило, что над вашим сообшением крупным шрифтом стояло "Ваш ответ"? Для новых воросов воспользуйтесь кнопкой [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), а это  сообшение пожалуйста удалите.